# Firefox shows images with no source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I have an image that is reserved for when someone clicks an icon link to display the full sized image. When the page initially loads in just Firefox (primary browsers used by the client base are Chrome, IE, and FF), it shows the broken image icon. Ideally without having to add much, if any additional code I'd like this to simply automatically be hidden. I attempted using `Visible="false"` but the issue when I tried to get the Javascript to update it to true using `attrib`, and I tried changing the `Visibility` in the CSS as well. In either case it did nothing for me. The code in general works great, just this one of the little quirk needs to be resolved and I can't seem to get it.

Below is the div that contains the image:

```
<div id="overlayContent" >
    <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgFull" ImageUrl="" CssClass="fullView" />
</div>
```

Help is greatly appreciated, I spent almost 8 hours trying to debug this myself and just no luck.

Comment: How does the image gets its source when it does - via server-side code or via JS?

Comment: `<asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgFull" ImageUrl="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" CssClass="fullView" />` <- hack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was simpler than I thought. Simply setting the CSS to `Display:None` on initialize and then setting it to `Display:Block` when it was time to show the image solved it. Cross browser friendly as well.